# Flutter pass touch event from top screen (new pushed widget) to previus stack screen(widget)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am making a DraggablePanel plugin in flutter. Similar to DraggablePannel in android which enables you to dock the top part(section) in bottom right of the screen and you are able to touch the elements of the previous fragment (screen).

What I am struggling with is to pass touch event to previous screen. I am not sure if its possible or not. I have used `IgnorePointer` but for that widgets need to be in same `Stack` widget or it has to be child/parent situation.

I need something with which I can pass touch from new pushed widget to previous stacked widget.

**UPDATE**
I have pushed my code on https://github.com/Siddharth-Dev/draggable_panel_flutter

I am able to get the touch events if I place the parent inside the `DragablePanel` stack.
Please check the `DraggablePannelWithParent` class in the above mentioned repository, which as of now the working solution for me.

Let me know if you found anything else.

Comment: can you edit your question with the `IgnorePointer` implementation code ?

Comment: @Abhishek I have pushed my code, please check example 3 for IgnorePointer use. https://github.com/Siddharth-Dev/draggable_panel_flutter